# Phone Auth verification cant verify and throws this error

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

Am getting this error and i cant tell what is this error of the firbase internal and i cant tell whats the problem so far i can tell its from the firebase themselves or anyone who has encountered

```
@Override
public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
    // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
    // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
    Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    mVerificationInProgress = false;
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
        // Invalid request
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        mPhoneNumberField.setError("Namba Ya Simu Si Sahihi.");
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
        // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Quota exceeded.",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }

    // Show a message and update the UI
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    updateUI(STATE_VERIFY_FAILED);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
```

> W/VerifyPhoneCustomer: onVerificationFailed
>       com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ 7: ]
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdv.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:18)
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzex.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:3)
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzfa.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:4)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)

Comment: Have you enabled `phone` authentication in your firebase project?

Comment: have enabled it in the console is should enalbe it on the project again in the studio @Md.Asaduzzaman if so how

Comment: Check 2nd part here: https://blog.usejournal.com/firebase-email-and-password-authentication-for-android-e335c81a1dad

Comment: Also check your internet connection

Comment: yes brother it has @Md.Asaduzzaman